# Finding Groups with common direct members. Active Directory

Tags: active-directory

I am currently using a tool called AD Info but it does not perform the specific query that I need. I am trying to find groups within AD in which there are multiple members of a specified name.

For example, I want to find all the groups in which Bob izumi and Tammy Livingston are direct members. Right now I am manually doing this search and it is taking forever because I have to find out the common groups within 20 people...Is there a free tool out there to do this or an easy way?

Comment: Can someone please help me with the LDAP query if that is a possible way to do this?

Comment: I'm not able to test this but something similar to (&((givenName=Bob)(sn=izumi))|(givenName=Tammy)(sn=Livingston))
(memberOf="CN=securityGroupName,OU=organisationalUnit, DC=domainName, DC=com")) Should work. Also the following site lists all (if not most) of the AD property names so is good for referencing: http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm

Comment: @NeilHibbert this should give me the groups those people have in common as direct members right? I am suppose to find the common groups for 20 different departments with each department having 20-40 users...It is driving me nuts! Will take like 2 weeks of copy pasting and clicking..

Comment: Hmmm that previous one would return users, not groups, this one should return common groups: (&(objectClass=group)((member= )(member= )) but you will need to add the distinguished name for the user objects you wish to search for in the gaps I left in the (member= ) filters. Sorry without AD to hand I can't test these queries so I might be doing more harm than good...

Answer (score 0):

If by AD you mean Active Directory - then yes you should investigate writing LDAP queries...

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205(v=exchg.65).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx)

I'm not really much of an AD person but if I recall correctly security and distribution groups are made up of a combination of flags, so the query you write will need to look at these flags plus the object name properties.

There is a Windows snap-in called ASDI Edit which is good for LDAP queries because it shows you the AD properties as they are used in LDAP queries (as opposed to the friendly labels in the Users and Computers snap-in).